# Emit events between nested components grandchild to root component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have `wheels.component` nested to `car.component`.

**wheels.component:**

```
export class WheelsComponent {    
    @Output() onLoaded : EventEmitter<string>() = new EventEmitter<string>();

    private downloadAllFiles(url: string) {
        this.onLoaded.emit('Hello, World 1!');
        //some operations to wait
        this.onLoaded.emit('Hello, World 2!');

    };
}
```

Component `car.component` is not written at html page, but called through routing at **car-routing.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: 'sfactmessage/:id',
                component: CarComponent,
                resolve: {
                    card: cardResolver
                }
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CarRoutingModule {}
```

What I want is to handle event emitted from `wheels.component`, not at `car.component`, **but at app.component**.

Is it possible to handle event at `app.component`?

[The plunker sample is not working](http://plnkr.co/edit/EsEJw7jbkRw4aNJ9iJR0?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts) (sorry, this is my first plunkr example), but gives a view how my app is arranged.

Comment: Can you create a sample plunker with your project structure, because it's not really clear

Comment: Yes, it is possible to handle event-emitted @ (the root) app.component . I have done it without routes; but it should be possible with it too. if u can share the plunkr that would give perspective.

Comment: @Plankton I've added plunker, but it is not working cause it is my first time at plunkr.

Comment: @StepUp thanks I will have a look

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hello_ friend.

So basically if you want to use events globally in your application you can use a [Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html#create-the-heroservice) in combination with [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html)

In this case you create a service for example **car.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class CarService {
  onLoaded : EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

Then use this service in a child component to emit events like this **wheels.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { CarService }  from './car.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'wheels',
    template: '<a (click)="sendValues()"> Click me to send value </a>'
})
export class WheelsComponent {

    constructor(private carService:CarService ){}

    sendValues() {
       /* Use service to emit events that can be used everywhere in the application */
        this.carService.onLoaded.emit('Button in WheelsComponent was clicked ...');
    }; 
}
```

and then capture this event from **AppComponent** for example **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CarService }  from './cars/car.service';
import { Subscription }  from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `src/app.component.html`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{ 
  private subscription: Subscription;
  private loading = true;
  name = 'Angular'; 

  constructor(private carService: CarService){} 

  ngOnInit(){
    this.subscription = this.carService.onLoaded.subscribe((message) => {

      /*
        Here you receive events from anywhere where
        carService.onLoaded.emit() is used
      **/

        alert(`From AppComponent -> ${message}`);
    });
  } 

  ngOnDestroy(){
    /* Don't forget to unsubscribe when component is destroyed */
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**I M P O R T A N T______________**

If you want your service to work **globally** you need to declare it in the top level **providers** for example **app.module.ts** is a good place:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { CarComponent} from './cars/car.component';
import { WheelsComponent} from './cars/wheels.component';
import { HomeComponent} from './home.component';
import { routing }  from './app.routing';
import { CarService }  from './cars/car.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CarComponent, WheelsComponent, HomeComponent ],
  providers: [ CarService ], // <-------- SEE HERE
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[**CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HsVHsaLOiE8iPsL1wZea?open=src%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview)

Comment: thanks! Is it possible to emit without using service? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do NOT import * from 'rxjs'!!! You are asking typescript to load the entire rxjs library that way. Instead import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'

Comment: GREAT! Thank you so much! Now I was able to implement a more dynamic navigation thanks to this trick.