# Post/Get data from service doesn't work like it should

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

To pass data around few components I created a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class Services {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("lol");
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {
  }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message);
    console.log(message);
  }

}
```

I create string messagesource for contain the passing data, and current message for Observable. And after that I create function to change this data.

So now, In ngOnInit() in one of component, I write:

```
this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
```

and define in component message:string save there message.

In function I make:

```
selectNews(news) {
  this.data.changeMessage("lol3"); // string for test
}
```

And after that, I want to get this string in other component

So again in ngOnInit, I copy the same line and define the message. But the consolelog here show me the string before function make action....

So were is the problem?

Edit
Fiddle with all whole code :

https://jsfiddle.net/fywdzz51/

Comment: The end of your post is not very clear and it's difficult to help. Maybe you could share the code of your other component ?

Comment: I add fiddle with code :)

Comment: This question is a real mess .... There are no POSTs OR GETs ... you want to **Emit** from service. I just answer similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44130831/5452965 you need to emit messages between your components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are providing the service separately for each component. this creates different instances in each component. you should provide it in one place for the whole module